# vmware network installation problem

Tags: vmware, virtualization

After installation from vmware_bunddle it shows network device error during configuration(First run).

[image]

Log File:

```
2012-04-03T20:01:24.881+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Log for VMware Workstation pid=5766 version=8.0.2 build=build-591240 option=Release
2012-04-03T20:01:24.881+06:00| vthread-3| I120: The process is 64-bit.
2012-04-03T20:01:24.881+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2012-04-03T20:01:24.881+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Host is Linux 3.2.0-19-generic Ubuntu precise (development branch)
2012-04-03T20:01:24.880+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2012-04-03T20:01:24.880+06:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2012-04-03T20:01:24.880+06:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2012-04-03T20:01:24.880+06:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2012-04-03T20:01:24.880+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2012-04-03T20:01:24.880+06:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2012-04-03T20:01:24.880+06:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2012-04-03T20:01:24.880+06:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2012-04-03T20:01:24.880+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2012-04-03T20:01:24.880+06:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2012-04-03T20:01:24.880+06:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2012-04-03T20:01:24.881+06:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2012-04-03T20:01:24.881+06:00| vthread-3| W110: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/modconfig-5766.log
2012-04-03T20:01:25.200+06:00| vthread-3| I120: modconf query interface initialized
2012-04-03T20:01:25.201+06:00| vthread-3| I120: modconf library initialized
2012-04-03T20:01:25.269+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:25.278+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:01:25.278+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2012-04-03T20:01:25.278+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.278+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:01:25.284+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:25.306+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:25.355+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.355+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:01:25.362+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:25.383+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:25.434+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.502+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.507+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.511+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.516+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.521+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.561+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.566+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.571+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.576+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.581+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.586+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:01:25.586+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2012-04-03T20:01:25.586+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.586+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:01:25.593+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:25.614+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:25.663+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.740+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.747+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.752+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.757+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.762+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.767+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:01:25.767+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2012-04-03T20:01:25.767+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2012-04-03T20:01:25.767+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:01:25.772+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:25.792+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:25.843+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:01:26.838+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:26.848+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:26.853+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:26.858+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:26.863+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:28.460+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:28.460+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:01:28.466+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:28.488+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:28.542+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:01:28.542+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmmon.
2012-04-03T20:01:28.553+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmmon module.
2012-04-03T20:01:28.615+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:36.499+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmmon from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc.
2012-04-03T20:01:36.507+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc/vmmon.ko
2012-04-03T20:01:58.314+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:01:58.315+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:01:58.336+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:58.379+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:01:58.431+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:01:58.431+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmnet.
2012-04-03T20:01:58.431+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmnet module.
2012-04-03T20:01:58.541+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-04-03T20:02:05.973+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to compile module vmnet!
2012-04-03T20:02:05.984+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:02:05.984+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:02:05.990+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:02:06.015+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:02:06.067+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:02:06.067+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmblock.
2012-04-03T20:02:06.067+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmblock module.
2012-04-03T20:02:06.141+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-04-03T20:02:13.531+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmblock from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc.
2012-04-03T20:02:13.532+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc/vmblock.ko
2012-04-03T20:02:19.090+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:02:19.090+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:02:19.097+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:02:19.117+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:02:19.173+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:02:19.173+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmci.
2012-04-03T20:02:19.174+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmci module.
2012-04-03T20:02:19.284+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-04-03T20:02:28.525+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmci from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc.
2012-04-03T20:02:28.526+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc/vmci.ko
2012-04-03T20:02:31.760+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:02:31.760+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:02:31.766+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:02:31.786+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:02:31.838+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:02:31.838+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmci.
2012-04-03T20:02:31.839+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmci module.
2012-04-03T20:02:31.864+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-04-03T20:02:33.684+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vsock.
2012-04-03T20:02:33.685+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vsock module.
2012-04-03T20:02:33.809+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-04-03T20:02:41.050+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vsock from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc.
2012-04-03T20:02:41.051+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc/vsock.ko
2012-04-03T20:03:02.757+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:02.762+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:02.767+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:02.771+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:02.776+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:02.782+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:03:02.782+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2012-04-03T20:03:02.782+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2012-04-03T20:03:02.782+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:03:02.790+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:02.814+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:02.865+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:03:02.958+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:02.968+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:02.973+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:02.978+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:02.983+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:04.372+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:04.372+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:03:04.378+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:04.399+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:04.452+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:03:04.452+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmmon.
2012-04-03T20:03:04.452+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmmon module.
2012-04-03T20:03:04.486+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:05.976+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmmon from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc.
2012-04-03T20:03:05.977+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc/vmmon.ko
2012-04-03T20:03:09.056+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:09.057+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:03:09.065+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:09.090+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:09.142+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:03:09.142+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmnet.
2012-04-03T20:03:09.142+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmnet module.
2012-04-03T20:03:09.169+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:12.072+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to compile module vmnet!
2012-04-03T20:03:12.090+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:12.090+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:03:12.098+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:12.121+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:12.179+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:03:12.179+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmblock.
2012-04-03T20:03:12.179+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmblock module.
2012-04-03T20:03:12.205+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:15.340+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmblock from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc.
2012-04-03T20:03:15.341+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc/vmblock.ko
2012-04-03T20:03:18.451+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:18.451+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:03:18.457+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:18.480+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:18.531+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:03:18.531+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmci.
2012-04-03T20:03:18.531+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmci module.
2012-04-03T20:03:18.569+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:19.787+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmci from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc.
2012-04-03T20:03:19.789+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc/vmci.ko
2012-04-03T20:03:22.933+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.2.0-19-generic.
2012-04-03T20:03:22.933+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic
2012-04-03T20:03:22.939+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:22.959+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:23.009+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.2.0-19-generic is valid.
2012-04-03T20:03:23.009+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmci.
2012-04-03T20:03:23.009+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmci module.
2012-04-03T20:03:23.034+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:24.227+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vsock.
2012-04-03T20:03:24.227+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vsock module.
2012-04-03T20:03:24.254+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2012-04-03T20:03:26.125+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vsock from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock.o to /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc.
2012-04-03T20:03:26.126+06:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.2.0-19-generic/misc/vsock.ko
```

My System details:

```
cpu : AMD APU dual core E450
ram: 2GB
ubuntu: 12.04 (64 bit)
```

I have downloaded Latest vmware version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Platform:

- Linux ici-Precision-M4400 3.2.0-23-generic-pae #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 22:19:09 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Found solution on:
http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/2012/01/26/vmware-workstation-8-0-2-player-4-0-2-fix-for-linux-kernel-3-2-and-3-3/

Extracted contents and ran below script to fix VMWorkstation.

```
sudo ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
```

Comment: does not work!!